Eclipse PHP code folding functionality does not work
SETUP
Eclipse Version: 2024-06 (4.32.0)
PHP Development Tools (PDT) 8.2.0.202311292129
PROBLEM
Code folding option is only available for HTML, but not for PHP
When pressing CTRL + /, the code moves slightly to the right and then back its original position if press CTRL + / again.
CTRL + / also eliminates code folding for HTML and reopening the file is needed to regain code folding.
SOLUTIONS TRIED
Followed instructions:

windows | preferences | php | editor | code editor | code folding => enabled
left click | folding | enable folding
CTRL + /
No change in behavior listed above.

Listed Below are images of the behavior(place where folding button should/is is in the red circle):





You talk about code without showing it. Please provide a minimal example with which your issue can be reproduced.

edited the question to illustrate the problem better.

Where is the code that can be easily copied and pasted to reproduce your problem? What do the cropped screenshots show (which editors and which file types)?
